# What is the Activity Id in AWS SWF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

When you schedule an Activity in AWS SWF, you have to provide an activity id:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/557cf674dfbb/aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/model/ScheduleActivityTaskDecisionAttributes.java#L68-L78

What's the meaning and scope of this id? Should it be unique for every invocation of a workflow? Or is it purely for my own information purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe *activityId* should be unique among all currently scheduled or executing activities. It is used at least to reference activity when requesting its cancellation through [RequestCancelActivityTask](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_RequestCancelActivityTaskDecisionAttributes.html) decision.

Comment: Really good point to reference RequestCancelActivityTask, thanks!